# DllImport - Works in test context, but not in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am working on an ASP.NET MVC application that calls out to a 3rd party library through `DllImport`.

Originally, when testing out how `DllImport` worked using MSTest, I wrote some simple tests to ensure I was using it properly.  I was able to use the entire API without an issue. As abstractions were built around the imports, the tests continued to show that the imports were working as expected and I was able to communicate with the external API.

Now I am starting to access that library in the context of ASP.NET MVC (instead of MSTest).  Whenever I make a call to the import, I encounter the following exception:

```
System.AccessViolationException: Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.
```

Is there anything I should be doing in order to use `DllImport` in ASP.NET MVC?

Below you can find an example of the initialization import.

```
[DllImport("pcrsrv32.dll", EntryPoint = "PCRSInitSrv", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern int InitSrv(string callerName, string iniFile);
```

When it comes to what this looks like in the 3rd party library, we are only provided the following for what the C function declaration looks like:

```
HRESULT _PCRSFN PCRSInitSrv(const char *name, const char *iniFile);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After using Process Monitor to profile the differences between accessing the external code in MSTest vs ASP.NET MVC, I found that ASP.NET MVC was unable to find many of the files that the external code relied on. When looking for the files, all folders included in my `PATH` were checked, but not the one I provided in the `ini` file sent to the external software.  When running through MSTest, all files were immediately found without an issue.

In the end, I was able to 'fix' the issue by adding the folder path to my `PATH` variable.  I'm not entirely happy with the fix, but it works now.

Answer (score 0):

On **windows** the **default** calling convention is **StdCall**.

Try to use: CallingConvention = `CallingConvention.StdCall`

Comment: Originally, I allowed the `CallingConvention` to use the default.  I only recently switched over to trying `Cdecl`.  I just attempted to explicitly use `StdCall` with no luck :(

Comment: Can you show the code how original InitSrv method looks like?

Comment: Looks fine. Do you run your MVC app in IIS or VS dev environment? Can you try to run MVC app as admin?

Comment: It's currently running locally on IIS Express. Anything special I need to do to run the app as admin?  Can't say I've done that before.