# ASP.NET MVC 4: Stackoverflow exception when using [DLLImport]

Tags: c#, c++, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm using c++ morphology library mcr.dll and it's work fine when i use it in C# Console Application, but when I'm trying to run this code in ASP.NET MVC4 Controller it fails at "getlemma()" method, at line "LoadMcr(s)" with System.StackOverflowException. Please, help me to understand, why mvc controller doens't want to make this work like it does in console app?

P.S.: there were some problems when i've tryed to run it in Console Application, like messages about  "PInvoke "ConsoleApplication1!ConsoleApplication1.morph::LoadMc unbalanced stack", but they disappeared when I add `"CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl".`

```
public string getlemma(string word)
    {
        InitMcr();
        string s = "zal.mcr";
        LoadMcr(s);
        Tids tt = new Tids();
        FindWID(word, ref tt);
        Tid t = tt.ids[0];
        Tinlexdata inlex = new Tinlexdata();
        GetWordById(t, false, false, ref inlex);
        return (inlex.inlex[0].anword);
    }
    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.StructLayoutAttribute(System.Runtime.InteropServices.LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct Tid
    {
        /// unsigned int
        public uint lnk;

        /// unsigned char
        public byte en;
    }
    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.StructLayoutAttribute(System.Runtime.InteropServices.LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct Tids
    {
        /// Tid[200]
        [System.Runtime.InteropServices.MarshalAsAttribute(System.Runtime.InteropServices.UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 200, ArraySubType = System.Runtime.InteropServices.UnmanagedType.Struct)]
        public Tid[] ids;
        /// int
        public int count;
    }
    // // InitMcr() - initialize dictionary 

    [DllImport("mcr.dll", CharSet = CharSet.None, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    public static extern int InitMcr();

    // // LoadMcr - load dictionary

    [DllImport("mcr.dll", CharSet = CharSet.None, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    public static extern int LoadMcr([System.Runtime.InteropServices.InAttribute()] [System.Runtime.InteropServices.MarshalAsAttribute(System.Runtime.InteropServices.UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string s);

    // // FindID - (find word in lemma dictionary)        
    [DllImport("mcr.dll", CharSet = CharSet.None, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    public static extern int FindWID([System.Runtime.InteropServices.InAttribute()] [System.Runtime.InteropServices.MarshalAsAttribute(System.Runtime.InteropServices.UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string s, ref Tids ids);

    // GetByID - (get lemma for a word) 
    [DllImport("mcr.dll", CharSet = CharSet.None, EntryPoint = "GetWordById", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    public static extern int GetWordById(Tid id, [System.Runtime.InteropServices.MarshalAsAttribute(System.Runtime.InteropServices.UnmanagedType.I1)] bool gh_only, [System.Runtime.InteropServices.MarshalAsAttribute(System.Runtime.InteropServices.UnmanagedType.I1)] bool all, ref Tinlexdata outdata);
```

Comment: Maybe this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21114865/dllimport-works-in-test-context-but-not-in-asp-net-mvc

Comment: CallingConvention.StdCall doesn't help. Also, acorrding to the last answer at your link, I've added string "D:\" (it's where zal.mcr also stored) to my system environment string PATH (I hope, that I understood answer correctly, or it should be some other "PATH"?) - the same problem, StackOverflow Exception. I've tryed to rename "zal.mcr" to not existing file "dasfasdf.mcr" = all is fine in that way, no exceptions, but LoadMcr(s) returns "-1", that means that dictionary not loaded so.. i think problem is not about access to "zal.mcr" file